# How to relate web-server with Docker-service in IToP CMDB?

Tags: cmdb

I'm exploring using IToPs CMDB to help manage some projects I'm working on. I have a server that runs Docker and a web-server running on Docker that hosts a web-application.

So the relationships/dependencies as I see them are:

Host-server -> Docker-service -> Web-server -> Web-application

When adding the web-server CI, there is an option to note the "system" which I used to link the web-server to host-server. But I can't figure out how to relate the docker-service to the web-server CI. How can I tell the system that the web-server needs the Docker-service?

I use this docker-compose to start IToP:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  my-itop:
    image: vbkunin/itop
    container_name: my-itop
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - my-itop-conf-volume:/var/www/html/conf
      - my-itop-db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - /home/user/itop-extensions:/var/www/html/extensions
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_NAME=itop
      - DB_USER=itop
      - DB_PASSWORD=itop
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: my-itop-db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=itop
      - MYSQL_USER=itop
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=itop
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-itop-conf-volume:
  my-itop-db-volume:
  db-data:
```